# How to create a hyperlink in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

This is my span tag and it displays "Hide subquestions". I want to create a hyperlink so the user knows it is clickable. How can i do that?

```
<span 
   onclick=
  "#hidejsfuncs#showHideElement
  ('h1_#qMocQuestionDetails.qnID#','none');
  showHideElement('v1_#qMocQuestionDetails.qnID#','');" 
  id="h1_#qMocQuestionDetails.qnID#" > #mocTrans.Translate("Hide 
  subquestions")#
</span>
```

Can anyone help me do this? Do I need JavaScript for this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a link then use an anchor `<a>` tag.  Something like this:

```
<a href="##"
   onclick=
   "#hidejsfuncs#showHideElement
   ('h1_#qMocQuestionDetails.qnID#','none');
   showHideElement('v1_#qMocQuestionDetails.qnID#','');" 
   id="h1_#qMocQuestionDetails.qnID#" > #mocTrans.Translate("Hide 
   subquestions")#
</a>
```

NOTE: I included two hashtags in the HREF because this code is nested between `<cfoutput>` tags. By using two hashtags the ColdFusion output will generate a single hashtag for the browser.

Comment: Thanks, i tried this works, but every time I click on my link it gets me to the page start.

Comment: Your JS onclick() isn't firing correctly. Use F12 or Developer Tools in your browser to see what JS is firing. Rather than dynamically building it in the anchor tag, you may need to build the final JS first.

Answer (score -1):

We can able to use like as below also,

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"
   onclick=
   "#hidejsfuncs#showHideElement
   ('h1_#qMocQuestionDetails.qnID#','none');
   showHideElement('v1_#qMocQuestionDetails.qnID#','');" 
   id="h1_#qMocQuestionDetails.qnID#" > #mocTrans.Translate("Hide 
   subquestions")#
</a>
```